# javascript change <p> display with buttons

Tags: javascript, paragraphs

I want to change the paragraphs visibility to none or hidden dynamicly using javascript.I have 4 paragraphs and I want only one to be displayed.If a user clicks right button the next parargraph should be displayed instead of the previous one.If left button, then another way.But my event handlers don't seem to respond inside the paragrap_switch function.Please help me with that

HTML

```
<head>
<style>
    p{
        border:1px solid black;
        width:20%;
        display:none;
    }
    input{
        width:40px;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="paragraph">TEXT 1</p>
<p class="paragraph">TEXT 2</p>
<p class="paragraph">TEXT 3</p>
<p class="paragraph">TEXT 4</p>

<input type = "button" value = "left"  class = "button"/>
<input type = "button" value = "right" class = "button"/>
```

And Javascript

```
function paragraph_switch (){
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByClassName('paragraph');
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
for(var i = 0;i < paragraphs.length; i++){
    if(i >= 0){
    if(buttons[0].onclick = function(){
        paragraphs[i].style.display = "none";
        paragraphs[i+1].style.display = "block";
        i++;
    }
    else if(buttons[1].onclick = function(){
        paragraphs[i].style.display = "none";
        paragraphs[i-1].style.display = "block";
        i--;
    }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your code is doing. You are assigning eventhandler inside the if condition. 
I have implemented your requirement using jQuery. Here is the jsfiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/DyZf2/

Here is the js code.

```
$("p:first").show();
$("#left").click(function(){
    $("p:visible").hide().prev().show();
});

$("#right").click(function(){
    $("p:visible").hide().next().show();
});
```

You may have to modify the code to make sure that next/previous paragraph exists before hiding the current one.